# Not able to instantiate a class in angular2

Tags: angular

I have a class like this

```
export class Policy {
    constructor() {
    }
    emailAddress: string;
    vehicleDetails: VehicleDetails[]
}

export class VehicleDetails {
    constructor(policynumber: string, vinnumber: string) {
        this.policyNumber = policynumber,
            this.vinNumber = vinnumber
    }
    policyNumber: string;
    vinNumber: string;
}
```

now i want to instantiate the class in the component like this, this is a submit method in which i bind the form values. but when i see the console i get an undefined error.

```
 var policy = new Policy();
    policy.emailAddress = formValue.controls.emailAddress._value;
    formValue.controls.policyDetails.controls.forEach(function (x) {
      policy.vehicleDetails.push(new VehicleDetails(x.controls.policyNumber._value, x.controls.vinNumber._value));
    });
```

why i am not getting the object.

**note:** I have not mentioned both of the class in the the @NgModule provider. My @NgModule is this

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LienholderComponent,
    AppComponent,
    PolicyVehicleComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      APP_ROUTES,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    ),
    BrowserModule,
    FileUploadModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],  
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: "why i am not getting the object." Which object do you not get where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possibly because you havent instantiated your vehicleDetails array

should be something like this:

```
export class Policy {
    constructor() {
    }
    emailAddress: string;
    vehicleDetails: VehicleDetails[] = [];
}
```